# Does 2 Corithians 3 17 say Jesus is the Holy Spirit

Tags: jesus, new-testament, 2-corinthians, trinity

Does this verse tell us that Jesus Christ is The Holy Spirit?

2 Corinthians 3 (KJV)
17 Now ***the Lord is that Spirit***: and where the Spirit of the Lord is, there is liberty.

What is THAT SPIRIT? Does this mean there is no THIRD PERSON in trinitarian view?